# Maximum value of the vandermonde polynomial

Tags: optimization

Let $n$ be an integer greater than 1. How must $n$ numbers $a_i$ in the interval 
$[0,1]$ be chosen that the vandermonde polynomial $$\prod_{i\ne j} (a_i-a_j) $$
has the maximum possible value ?

My conjecture, that the numbers must be equidistant, seems to be false
due to numerical analysis.

Comment: Yes I did, I realized why equidistant is false. (WLOG $a_i$ are in decreasing order) Note that if we increase $a_1$ to 1 and decrease $a_n$ to 0, we're only increasing each individual term (or stay constant), hence the product will increase.

Comment: If the product is taken symmetrically then the maximum is zero as it can never be strictly positive. If the product is only taken for $i<j$ the result might be different.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/15366

Comment: OK, I seems that this definition of the vandermonde polynomial is false because the value must be positive or 0. With i<j and (a(i)-a(j))^2 , the definition should be OK.

Comment: I really did not know that this question was already asked. Sorry.